# Yii index page does not print values inside a function

Tags: php, yii

php?r=site/index of my Yii demo application... i have put a function called hello there but it does not go inside that function(hello world does not get printed).. can anybody help me on this

```
    <?php
/* @var $this SiteController */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name;
?>
 // <h1>Welcome to <i><?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name); ?></i></h1>
 <?php

 function hello(){

     echo 'Hello world';
 }

?>
// <p>Congratulations! You have successfully created your Yii application.</p>

// <p>You may change the content of this page by modifying the following two files:</p>
// <ul>
    // <li>View file: <code><?php echo __FILE__; ?></code></li>
    // <li>Layout file: <code><?php echo $this->getLayoutFile('main'); ?></code></li>
// </ul>

// <p>For more details on how to further develop this application, please read
// the <a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/">documentation</a>.
// Feel free to ask in the <a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/">forum</a>,
// should you have any questions.</p>
```

Comment: Your issue is related to a misunderstanding of the usage of PHP functions. The function hello() is only called if you call it, which you are not doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only declared the function. You need to call the function to execute it.

```
function hello(){
    echo 'Hello world';
}
hello();
```

It is very bad style to declare a function within your view though. I think you should learn a bit more about programming in general before working with a framework.